# Can't Download Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am trying to download Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013 from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42313. But download link on microsoft does not work. Do you know any other place where i can download it?

Comment: What OS and browser are you using? What is the error message? (It works for me).

Comment: Microsoft and chrome, explorer. If it is working for you, probabily my network secure blocks it. Thank you.